# How do i only get matching object from nested array in mongodb using find or aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

My model
having this field :

```
canReview: [
    {
        status: {
            type: Boolean
        ,
    }
]
```

Records are :

```json
[
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: "aaaa",
      canReview: [
        {
          status: true
        },
        {
          status: false
        },
        {
          status: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: "abbb",
      canReview: [
        {
          status: false
        },
        {
          status: false
        },
        {
          status: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want the result like only status true records from nested array too
I query like :

```
{canReview.status : true}
```

result :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "aaaa",
    "canReview": [
      {
        "status": true
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

nested array contains only records those status is true...
Need more details explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$anyElementTrue`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    "$anyElementTrue": "$canReview.status"
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h5AmP3wALXX)